# Unexpected behaviour of read(n) in pySerial 3.3

Tags: python, serial-port, embedded, pyserial

I'm writing a project using an STM32F407_VG board that uses an RS232 connection to send batch of data of different sizes (~400 bytes) on a serial port, and those data must be written on file. On desktop side I'm using a python 3 script with pyserial 3.3.

I've tried reading a single byte at time with **ser.read()** but I think it's too slow because I'm losing some of the data. So I'm trying to send the size of the batch as an integer before the batch itself, in order to reduce the overhead, and write data to file during time interval within a batch and the following one.

**PROBLEM IS**: ser.read(n) behave in a very strange way, and 99% of the times it blocks when it's time to read the batch and do not return. It also happens that sometimes it can read the first batch and writes it to file successfully, but it blocks at the second loop iteration. It's strange because I can use ser.read(4) to get the batch size with zero problem, and I use ser.readline() at the beginning of the script when listening to a starting signal, but I cannot read the data.

I'm sure that data are there and are well formed because I checked with a logic analyzer, and I've already tried with enabling and disabling flow control or set different baud rates on both the board and the script. I think it could be a config problem of python, but actually I've run out of ideas.

---

**PYTHON SCRIPT CODE -SNIPPET**

```
ser = serial.Serial(str(sys.argv[1]),           \
                int(sys.argv[2]),               \
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,   \
                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,      \
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,      \
                timeout=None                    \
                )
outputFile = open(sys.argv[3],"wb")

# wait for begin string
beginSignal = "ready"
word = ""
while word != beginSignal:
   word = ser.readline().decode()
   word = sample.split("\n")[0]
print("Started receiving...")

while True:
   # read size of next batch
   nextBatchSize = ser.read(4)
   nextBatchSize = int.from_bytes(nextBatchSize,byteorder='little', signed=True)
   # reads the batch: 
   # THIS IS THE ONE THAT CREATES PROBLEMS
   batch = ser.read(nextBatchSize)
   # write data to file
   outputFile.write(batch)
```

**BOARD CODE - SNIPPET**

```
// this function sends the size of the batch and the batch itself
void sendToSerial(unsigned char* mp3data, int size){
   // send actual size of the batch
   write(STDOUT_FILENO,&size,sizeof(int));
   // send the batch of data
   write(STDOUT_FILENO,mp3data,size);
}
```

---

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have already tried this, but print out `nextBatchSize` to confirm that it is what you expect, just in case the byte order is reversed. If this is wrong your Python code could be trying to read too many bytes, and would therefore block.

Also you can check `ser.in_waiting` to see how many bytes are available to be read from the input buffer before your read attempt:

```
print(ser.in_waiting)
batch = ser.read(nextBatchSize)
```

You should also check the return value of `write()` in your C code, which is the number of bytes actually written, or -1 if there is an error. `write()` is not guaranteed to write all of the bytes in the given buffer, so there might remain some that have not been written. Or there might have been an error.

Data loss suggests a flow control issue. You need to ensure that it is enabled at both ends. You've said that you tried it, but in your posted code it is not enabled. How are you opening and configuring the serial port at the board end?

Comment: Yes I've checked `nextBatchSize` and it's correct and `write()` should be correct because I can see that data are correctly output with logic analyzer.
I'm not writing bare metal because I'm using an embedded OS written by my professor (Miosix OS) and I'm enabling flow control setting a flag at True in a config file so I'm not so sure about what I'm doing, but searching around I think I'm enabling RTSCTS. Enabling it on the script does not provide any improvement

Comment: @GiovanniBeri: good, what about the return value from `write()`?

Comment: @GiovanniBeri:  I have updated my answer to suggest using `ser.in_waiting` to check how many bytes are available before reading.

Comment: ok, using `inWaiting()` (it's not `in_waiting` anymore since pyserial3), I've seen that, when `read(nextBatchSize)` is blocked, the serial buffer is not empty but it does not contain the amount of bytes needed to unlock the `read(nextBatchSize)`. I made a cycle which prints for 1000 times the value of `inWaiting()` and I see that it start from 0 and increases, but it stops at a certain seemingly random value (e.g. `nextBatchSize == 400`, `inWaiting() == 200`). Do you think it could be caused by flow control issues?

Comment: @GiovanniBeri: Did you check the return value of `write()` on the board? Does it match the length of the data that you gave it?

Comment: The problem could be due to buffering in pySerial. The board side seems to be using low-level `open()`, `write()` so there should not be any buffering there. Here are a few things to try: 1) as a test try sending non-binary data from the board in case software flow control is somehow enabled, This might explain the inconsistent behaviour, 2) Try terminating the `write()` data with a newline character in case pySerial is buffering the input...

Comment: ... 3) On the desktop try a modem controller/terminal emulator such as `minicom` or pySerial's miniterm: http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#module-serial.tools.miniterm See whether it can receive all of the data sent.

Comment: ok, using `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 myBaudrate` as a terminal emulator (only because it's the one my professor suggested and I had already used it) I can see that it neither can receive all the data. So, by using logic analyzer, I know that all data are sent, but somehow they get lost during the communication, right? I've tried also suggestion 2) with no success. What do you mean by non-binary data in 1)? On the board I've set the serial outupt in raw mode using termios.h, do you mean that I could reconfigure it in ASCII?

Comment: @GiovanniBeri: re non-binary, the name `mp3data` suggests binary data which includes non-printable characters such as DC1 (0x11) and DC3 (0x13). These characters can have special meanings, in this case XON and XOFF which implement software flow control. So, as a test, avoiding those characters below 0x20 and above 0x7E _might_ reveal whether software flow control is enabled.

Comment: Interesting that `screen` is also having the same problem. Perhaps its something to do with the USB<->RS232 adapter? Is the received data truncated, or are random parts of it missing?